# How do I change the date format in App Preview and WebApps?

Tags: commcare

When I have a date question in a form, the result in App Preview is shown in the format "mm/dd/yyyy". I was hoping to have the date displayed in the format "dd/mm/yyyy" or "yyyy/mm/dd" to be less ambiguous. How would I go about doing this?

I tried changing my browser's locale, but that didn't change the way the date was displayed.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment, it is impossible to change the date format in Web Apps. It currently displays as MM/DD/YYYY (month/day/year).